# Spring webflux - how to return a DTO in a mono by looking up two concurrent calls that return a Mono and a Flux?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive

Somewhat new to reactive programming and can't find any good examples of this.  How would I combine results from a Mono and a Flux (concurrent fetches) to return a Mono of a DTO?

I know the code below won't compile but generally speaking I want to do something like the below.

Thanks in advance.

```
public Mono<UserDto> getByName(String name) {
    Mono<User> user = userRepo.findByName(name);
    Flux<PhoneNumber> numbers = phoneNumbersRepo.findByName(name);

    return Mono.zip(user, number) ... 
               UserDto dto = new UserDto();
               dto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
               dto.setPhoneNumbers(number);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to transform `Flux<PhoneNumber>` into `Mono<List<PhoneNumber>>` and then combine using `Mono.zip`

```
public Mono<UserDto> getByName(String name) {
    Mono<User> user = userRepo.findByName(name);
    Flux<PhoneNumber> numbers = phoneNumbersRepo.findByName(name);

    return Mono.zip(user, numbers.collectList())
            .map(res -> {
                UserDto dto = new UserDto();
                dto.setFirstName(res.getT1().getFirstName());
                dto.setPhoneNumbers(res.getT2());
                return dto;
            });
}
```